# How does Tor know which HSDir to connect to?

Tags: onion-services, hsdir

How does Tor know which HSDir to connect to to find the address in the hash table?

Let's say the address is `ro3jr3nvvn2223cd.onion`

How does tor know which HSDir will store this in their hash table?

Surely Tor cannot check every HSDir to see if it contains them, is there a way tor knows or does it actually manually check every HSDir?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Few questions about connecting to Tor hidden services](http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3430/few-questions-about-connecting-to-tor-hidden-services)

Answer (score 2):

This is described in detail in the [Tor Rendezvous Specification](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/rend-spec.txt).

Basically a client will check 6 HSDirs. It calculates which 6 nodes to check from the .onion address itself.

In the below explanation, *Bob* is the owner of the hidden service (i.e. the .onion site), and *Alice* is the person wanting to connect to the hidden service.

**Bob**

- Bob wants to advertise his *service descriptor* - basically a description of his hidden service. He does so by publishing his descriptor to a subset of all HSDirs.
- The size of this subset is **6 HSDirs**.
- He determines which 6 nodes to publish to by using the *consensus status document*, which he obtains from the Directory Authorities, and uses his .onion address to calculate the *descriptor-id*s of the 6 HSDirs to use.
- [For reference, see section *1.4 - Bob's OP advertises his service descriptor* of the specification mentioned above]

**Alice**

- Alice fetches Bob's service descriptor from one of these 6 HSDir nodes.
- To determine which nodes actually constitute these six, Alice fetches a list of all nodes in the network that have the HSDir flag set. She then calculates a *descriptor-id* from Bob's .onion address, which she uses to work out which six nodes Bob has published his descriptor to. (There are more details in this part - this is just the crux of what happens.)
- If Alice receives a 404 response from any of her attempts to connect to one of these HSDirs, she tries one of the other six nodes.
- [For reference, see sections *1.5 - Alice receives a z.onion address* and *1.6 - Alice's OP retrieves a service descriptor* of the above specification.]

You might also find [this](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3430/few-questions-about-connecting-to-tor-hidden-services) previous thread useful.